# Using Dday.ical How can I send multiple events with the same start time and duration

Tags: vb.net, outlook, icalendar

When I setup the event using DDay.ical I can successfully send the events to a user's outlook.  The problem arises when multiple events are setup at the same time.  When this happens all emails are updates to the original task, not new tasks.

I tried adding a name to the event using the .Name property, which results in the event email being an unsupported calendar invite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring this out through some good old trial and error.

In the end I was not properly setting the UID property to be a completely unique identifier for each event.  Changing this to be unique 100% of the time fixed the issue and allowed me to  be able to create as many events as I want, any time I want, and have them all appear as separate events instead of updates.